# Adding text to Tkinter Window - Formatting Specific String

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two arrays. One which is an array of titles for a snippet and the other array is full of the text for those snippets. I want to add the title and then relevant snippet to a Tkinter window, and I would like to make the title show up in bold/italics/whatever formatting I want.

```
for x in range(0, upper_bound):
   w.insert(Tkinter.INSERT,title_array[x] + "\n")
   w.insert(Tkinter.INSERT,snippet_array[x] + "\n\n")
```

How would I specify at the 'insert' stage that I want it in bold (for example)?

I realise that I am probably approaching this task in the wrong fashion, please do suggest a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a tag with the appropriate formatting, then give that tag when inserting the text.

```
w.tag_configure("heading", background="black", foreground="white")
...
for x in range(0, upper_bound):
    w.insert("insert", title_array[x] + "\n", "heading")
    w.insert("insert", snippet_array[x] + "\n\n")
```

you can insert multiple things with a single `insert` command if you want. The `insert` command can take multiple arguments of the form *text*, *tags*, *text*, *tags*, .... (you can omit the final tag, which is why you can call `insert` with just a single argument)

```
w.insert("insert", title_array[x]+"\n", heading, 
         snippet_array[x]+"\n\n")
```

Also, adding a tag to the trailing newline or not is what determines if the formatting extends to the right margin. For instance, compare the above with the following:

```
w.insert("insert", title_array[x], "heading",
         "\n" + snippet_array[x] + "\n\n")
```